# DataGridViewButtonColumn acting as DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I want to have `DataGridViewButtonColumn` acting as `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`. Meaning having some image inside the button as a `true` and another image as a `false` and bound to a property by `DataMember`.
I think a class inheriting from `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` and `override` the `paint` method "should" work.

Comment: So what's your question?  What have you tried?

Comment: so far i'm stuck in the paint method. don't know what to do in it

Comment: No need to inherit anything.  Just use the grid's CellPainting event.

Comment: @ihisham Did you try finding out how to draw an image in winforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` but handle `CellPaint` event of `DataGridView` and draw an image for checked state and another for unchecked state.

**Example**

Create a `Form` named `Form1` and then drop a `DataGridView` control on form and replace content of `Form1.cs` with following code. Also make sure you added `Checked` [image] and `UnChecked` [image] images to `Resources`.

Then you will see such result:

[image]

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Load += Form1_Load;
    this.dataGridView1.CellPainting += dataGridView1_CellPainting;
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(bool));
    dt.Rows.Add(false);
    dt.Rows.Add(true);
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        var value = (bool?)e.FormattedValue;
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All &
                                ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);
        var img = value.HasValue && value.Value ?
            Properties.Resources.Checked : Properties.Resources.UnChecked;
        var size = img.Size;
        var location = new Point((e.CellBounds.Width - size.Width) / 2,
                                    (e.CellBounds.Height - size.Height) / 2);
        location.Offset(e.CellBounds.Location);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, location);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: quick question i moved the code to a stand alone DataGridViewColumn so i can use it freely. it's working but i don't get the visual update when i'm in edit mode, the update takes effect only when i quit it. any idea why ?

Comment: Are you sure you derived from `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`? Hmmm, maybe it would be better to post a new question containing the code of the custom column which you created.

Comment: here i post the problem with the code used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46709110/custom-datagridviewcheckboxcell-visual-update-doesnt-work-in-edit-mode